# is there any solution to find jwt token in flutter app using aws amplify

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am implementing authentication in flutter app using AWS amplify using google identity provider (sign in with google) but I am facing trouble in getting the JWT token and I have to pass this JWT token to call the API in the backend.????
i am not geting jwt token in my flutter app.